# Conditional filtering into 'blocks' of data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this set of data that is in time series windows, and this is how the plot looks like:

[image]

As you can see, sometimes the y-axis becomes 0 and sometimes it doesn't.
How do I 'chop' it into different blocks of graph?

Or rather, how do I find the beginning and end of points of 'Window No.' where the y-axis = 0?

In the above example, visually I could tell there are 9 'blocks', so how can I filter it to 9 different 'blocks' of data frame?

This is a sample of how the data looks like

```
Time                Window No.  Port ME Homemade Mass Flow Rate (kg/s)  
2019-05-28 11:15:00 0   0.065305
2019-05-28 11:30:00 1   0.072700
2019-05-28 11:45:00 2   0.075495
2019-05-28 12:00:00 3   0.074969
2019-05-28 12:15:00 4   0.071545
... ... ...
2020-10-24 15:00:00 49455   0.000000
2020-10-24 15:15:00 49456   0.000000
2020-10-24 15:30:00 49457   0.000000
2020-10-24 15:45:00 49458   0.049100
2020-10-24 16:00:00 49459   0.048364
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I used this line

```
df1before.loc[df1before['Port ME Homemade Mass Flow Rate (kg/s)'] > 0, ['Window No.']]
```

and it managed to return me 'Window No' when it is greater than 0. Works pretty well. Now, this returns me

```
Index  Window No.
0      2671
1      2672
2      2673
3      2674
4      2675
```

Eventually, the Window No. will stop adding by 1. That will be the end of the first block, and the beginning of the second block. How do I write a line to detect a change, whereby the change is +1 of Window No.?

Comment: I think you are looking for a change point detection algorithm, there is a package called [ruptures](https://github.com/deepcharles/ruptures/) that maybe useful. For plotting a [broken axis, see this matplotlib demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html). Also, [please do not upload images of code, errors, or data when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thanks Alex, I've changed my data image!

Comment: @Yi Hong Quek has my proposed answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

### finding peaks

Let's assume this input:

```
s = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,10,11,12,0,0,0,15,14,13,0,0,0,0,8,9])
```

[image: data]

First, find the peaks/background using threshold:

```
peaks = s.gt(0) # here threshold is 0, but it could be anything
```

Get the first value of each peak:

```
(peaks ^ peaks.shift())
```

Same + number the peak by group:

```
(peaks ^ peaks.shift()).cumsum().mask(~peaks)
```

full code:

```
pd.concat({'data': s,
           'peak_groups': (peaks ^ peaks.shift()).cumsum().mask(~peaks)},
          axis=1).dropna()
```

output:

```
    data  peak_groups
4     10          1.0
5     11          1.0
6     12          1.0
10    15          3.0
11    14          3.0
12    13          3.0
17     8          5.0
18     9          5.0
```

NB. This numbers the peaks with odd numbers, if you want to have consecutive groups you can replace `(peaks ^ peaks.shift())` with `(peaks & (peaks ^ peaks.shift()))`

### plotting

How to plot subgraphs:

```
f, (axes) = plt.subplots(ncols=len(df['peak_groups'].unique()), sharey=True)

i = 0
for group, d in df.groupby('peak_groups'):
    axes[i].plot(d['data'])
    axes[i].set_title('peak %d' % group)
    i+=1
```

[image: peak subgraphs]